# Ruby: Join with ActiveRecord using non-standard schema

Tags: ruby, activerecord, join

I'm struggling to make a join between tables work on a non-standard schema. I know the proper way of doing it would be migrating the schema and using the ActiveRecord convention but as long as I'm using this to consume data for testing purposes, that's not an option.

The join can be made using the key 'AGREEMENT_TYPE_ID' that exists in both tables.

I have the following in the models definition:

```
class Agreements < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'AGREEMENTS'
    self.primary_key = 'AGREEMENT_ID'
    has_one :Agreement_Types, :foreign_key => 'AGREEMENT_TYPE_ID'
end

class Agreement_Types < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :Agreements
    self.table_name = 'AGREEMENT_TYPES'
    self.primary_key = 'AGREEMENT_TYPE_ID'
end
```

This is the instantiation:

```
puts Agreements.joins(:Agreement_Types)
```

This is the output:

```
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in     `compute_type': uninitialized constant Agreements
::AgreementTypes (NameError)
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency/join_association.rb:40:in `initialize'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:152:in `new'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:152:in `build_join_association'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:115:in `build'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:123:in `block in build'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:122:in `each'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:122:in `build'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:18:in `initialize'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:358:in `new'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:358:in `build_joins'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:266:in `build_arel'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:260:in `arel'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/explain.rb:25:in `logging_query_plan'
        from C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
        from C:in `to_ary'
        from prueba.rb:29:in `puts'
        from prueba.rb:29:in `puts'
        from prueba.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try to run `defined? Agreements`

Comment: Regardless of the non-standard naming of your tables, IMO you should name your models properly, i.e. `Agreement` instead of `Agreements` and `AgreementType` instead of `Agreement_Types`.

Comment: Thanks @MladenJablanović. I think you are completely right and will follow your advice on that.

Comment: @denis.peplin it returns nothing, but when I execute 'puts Agreements.find(:first).agreement_id' it return the content correctly

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution that works:

```
class AgreementType < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'AGREEMENT_TYPES'
    self.primary_key = 'AGREEMENT_TYPE_ID'
    belongs_to :Agreement
end

class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'AGREEMENTS'
    self.primary_key = 'AGREEMENT_ID'
    has_one :AgreementType, :primary_key => 'AGREEMENT_TYPE_ID', :foreign_key => 'AGREEMENT_TYPE_ID'
end
```